# How to capture elements sorted using jQuery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI sortable and attempting to drag and drop table rows as sortable items. So far, I've gotten the rows to drag and drop along with a fix to preserve the rows width. However, I'm unsure how to actually capture the result of the sorted rows.

There's an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/tzYbU/) that I'm working with and it shows what I'm looking for. My problem (I think) is how I adapted the cited example from list elements to table rows. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

This is my HTML table which I'm attempting to sort.

```
<pre> 
    <div id="info">Waiting for update</div> 
</pre>

<table class="u-full-width alternate" id="sort">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="listItem_116"><img src="/images/arrows.png" class="handle" /> Restaurants</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="listItem_117"><img src="/images/arrows.png" class="handle" /> Automotive</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="listItem_117"><img src="/images/arrows.png" class="handle" /> Retail</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My javascript is a mashup of the example fiddle provided and also a fix to preserve the width of the table row.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Return a helper with preserved width of cells
        var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
            ui.children().each(function() {
                $(this).width($(this).width());
            });
            return ui;
        };

        $("#sort tbody").sortable({
            helper: fixHelper
        }).disableSelection();

        $("#sort tbody").sortable({
            handle : '.handle',
            update : function () { 
                var order = $('#sort').sortable('serialize');
                $('#info').load("process-sortable.php?"+order); 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Finally I've got the PHP file to process the results. At this point it just prints the results but that's enough for me to keep moving. This is where I should be seeing the result of sortable but am not.

```
<?php 
/**
 * This is where you would inject your sql into the database 
 * but we're just going to format it and send it back 
 */ 

foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item)
{
    $sql[] = "UPDATE `table` SET `position` = $position WHERE `id` = $item"; 
}
print_r ($sql); 
?>
```

I've put this same HTML and javascript into a fiddle in the event that it might help diagnose the javascript issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/wypzz854/1/

Comment: So where do you send the info to the php? Can you show us your form?

Comment: @MrJack there is no form. And `load()` is an ajax method

Comment: I should have included the original tutorial I used which does include a form, though I wasn't entirely sure what it's purpose was given that removing it didn't affect the functionality. http://linssen.me/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/

Comment: In that example, they use the same id for order and the sortable, you don't, so you need to do it with a form.

Comment: @MrJack there is no need for a form. Lots of ajax is done with data that has no form involved

Comment: The code he posted cannot be done without a form, to use without a form you need to use the same element for the sortable and the serialized parameters. Also, there always is a form, that's what serialize does...

Comment: @MrJack read the `sortable` docs and look at my demo. That is not correct. You are thinking of `jQuery.serialize()` which is a form method but that is not what is being used here

Comment: The demo you post uses the same selector though, with $(this) so if it doesn't break other parts of his existing code he can use that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems.

The id should be on the sortable elements which are the `<tr>`.

Change:

```
<tr>
    <td id="listItem_116"></td>
</tr>
```

TO:

```
<tr id="listItem_116">
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Your sort selector is `$("#sort tbody")` but inside the update event you are trying to serialize the parent table using `$("#sort")`

Try  this:

```
$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    handle : '.handle',
    update : function (e, ui) { 
        // we want to serialize "this"
        var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');            
        $('#info').load("process-sortable.php?"+order); 
    } 
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wypzz854/5/)**</kbd>